# How to get first and second records from a table having has_many relation in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, has-many

I am having a relation where **contacts** :*has_many* **emails** and **email** :*belongs_to* **contacts**.
my contacts.xls.erb file:

```
class ContactsXLS < BaseXLS
  def add_content
   contacts.each do |contact|
    write_array [contact.title,
    contact.updated_at,
    contact.email,
    contact.phone,
    first_email(contact),
    second_email(contact) ]
   end
  end

  def first_email(contact)
    contact.emails.each do |emm|
    emmm.first.email
    end
  end
  def second_email(contact)
    contact.emails.each do |emm|
    emmm.last.email
    end
  end
```

end

I have to add email fields from emails table which belongs for a particular contact in above file.
Here the relation between 2 tables is:
**emailable_id** in *emails* table = **id** in *contacts* table.

I tried in console as :

```
c =Contact.find('1wqwqwqw212121')
c.emails.first.email #ex@ex.com
```

I think we need to write a method and call this array but I couldn't. My requirement is to print first record and second record, please help.

Comment: `c.emails.limit(2)` wiill give first and second record

Comment: I need to add in method (first_email) as shown in the above code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the relation **contacts** :*has_many* **emails**,
we can write in array as:

```
contact.emails.first.try(:email)
```

likewise for displaying the first record.

Answer (score 0):

You can rewrite those methods

There already have finder methods of `first second,..forty_two` for rails also you can get any data by using index like `find_nth`

You can read more on [finder methods](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/FinderMethods.html)

[First](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/FinderMethods.html#method-i-first) and [Second](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/FinderMethods.html#method-i-second)

```
def first_email(contact)
  contact.emails.first.email
end

 def second_email(contact)
  contact.emails.second.email   
 end
```

Then

```
c =Contact.find('1wqwqwqw212121')
ContactsXLS.new.first_email(c)
ContactsXLS.new.second_email(c)
```

Comment: I am not getting error ContactsXLS doen't exist. I think we should not mention this. Just we have to write method and just call in array.